# User is not authorized to perform: iam:CreatePolicy on resource: policy AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole?

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-iam

Logged in as IAM user and trying to create lambda function but seeing below error, what is missing her?

```
User: arn:aws:iam::123334324324234:user/abx.dsd@rr.com is not authorized to perform: iam:CreatePolicy on resource: policy AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole-e3e28520-4b65-439e-a006-24de73479562
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you create a AWS Lambda in the AWS Console a few things are done in the background by AWS. One such thing is creating a role/policy for your Lambda automatically.

To do so, your user (`arn:aws:iam::123334324324234:user/abx.dsd@rr.com`) needs the `iam:CreatePolicy` permission.

This is something a account administrator can fix for you.

Answer (score 4):

adding `iam:CreateRole` is not enough, you need to add also several other permissions to the user, something like this

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:AttachRolePolicy",
                "iam:CreateRole",
                "iam:CreatePolicy",
                "iam:PutRolePolicy"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Note. I am not sure that all these policies are required.

Comment: it was adding the "iam:PutRolePolicy" permission that worked for me

Comment: If you're not sure if all these roles are required, better to not suggest this as a solution. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege