# AWS IAM no identity-based policy allows the iam

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

I am a AWS beginner and must use for university . I cannot perform an IAM actions such as create roles , users absolutely nothing
However , i keep getting is "xxx is not authorized to perform: iam:Createroeon resource: * because no identity-based policy allows the iam:Createrole action * . I keeping the same error .

Anyway i could fix this?

Comment: If you are using AWS Academy, then there is no way to fix that. Its hard limit.

Comment: If you have an AWS account administrator, talk to that person. They probably didn't give you any creative or destructive IAM permissions, and deliberately so because you probably (in their eyes) don't need them.

Comment: When you say that you "keep getting" that error, what are you doing that causes that error?

Comment: I am trying to create a new role ,

Comment: See the solution here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/74874094/3139228

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ANSWER**

AWS EDUCATE Accounts do not allow you to create roles or users